# R: replace value of columns for other columns based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Timestamp      Value1    Value2    Problem1    Problem2
    00:00          32        40          No          No
    00:05          12        55          No          No
    00:10          14        42         Yes          No
    00:15          50        33         Yes          No
    00:20          78        47          No          No
```

Where `Problem1` defines if there is a problem with `Value1`, and `Problem2` defines if there is a problem with `Value2`. In case of having a `Yes` in `Problem1`, I'd need to replace `Value1` by `Value2`. In case of having problems in both, they should keep unchanged.

My problem here is that I won't know how many `Value` and `Problem` columns I'll have. So, in case of having more than 2, I'd need to replace the value with problems by the average of those values without problems.

So, in another example:

```
Timestamp      Value1    Value2    Value3    Problem1    Problem2    Problem3
    00:00          32        40        45          No          No          No
    00:05          12        55        48          No          No          No
    00:10          14        42        55         Yes          No          No
    00:15          50        33        13         Yes          No         Yes
    00:20          78        47        75          No          No          No
```

Here I'd need to replace `Value1` at `00:10` by the average of `Value2` and `Value3`. Also, I'd need to replace `Value1` and `Value3` at `00:15` by `Value2`.

Comment: Is your Timestamp a unique id for each line?

Comment: Yes! It's unique

Comment: Could you please post a reusable code/data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't share my original dataset, actually... I've thought about a for loop for iterating for each `Value` and `Problem` case, but I'm pretty stuck at how to make it generic enough for any number of values and problem columns

Comment: @MustardRecord, you don't need to share the whole dataset. You can just use the `dput()` function in the subset you shared here. It makes easier to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet there is a more elegant solution.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Problem"), ~ .x == "Yes")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Timestamp, names_to = c("name", "id"), names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)") %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>%
  group_by(Timestamp) %>%
  mutate(Value = case_when(sum(Problem) == 0 | sum(Problem) == n() | !Problem ~ Value,
                               TRUE~ sum(Value * (1 - Problem))/sum(1-Problem))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c("Value", "Problem")) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0(name,id), .keep="unused") %>%
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Problem"), ~ ifelse(.x == 1, "Yes", "No")))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Timestamp Value1 Problem1 Value2 Problem2 Value3 Problem3
  <time>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
1 00'00"      32   No           40 No           45 No      
2 05'00"      12   No           55 No           48 No      
3 10'00"      48.5 Yes          42 No           55 No      
4 15'00"      33   Yes          33 No           33 Yes     
5 20'00"      78   No           47 No           75 No
```

What approach did I use?

- Transform your Problem Variable into a boolean. R is able to use booleans in calculations, technically it is transformed later into a double.
- Turn your value/problem numbers into a id, so for every timestamp there are several rows for Value and Problem.
- Calculate the new value based on the number of problems and if the value is problematic.
- Restore the shape of your data.frame.

### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(0, 300, 600, 900, 1200
), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), Value1 = c(32, 
12, 14, 50, 78), Value2 = c(40, 55, 42, 33, 47), Value3 = c(45, 
48, 55, 13, 75), Problem1 = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), 
    Problem2 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), Problem3 = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "No")), problems = structure(list(row = 5L, 
    col = "Problem3", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), Value1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Value2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Value3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Problem1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Problem2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Problem3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I'm curious: Is there an easier/more simple way for my `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` functions? Is it able to do those operations in one step?

Answer (score 0):

I use the data.table package. I call your data given in the second example "din".
I hope this code helps you:

```
#I use the library data.table; get data in data.table format
library(data.table)
din <- data.table(din)
din[,Value1:=as.numeric(Value1)]
din[,Value2:=as.numeric(Value2)]
din[,Value3:=as.numeric(Value3)]

#set Values to NA if there is a Problem
din[Problem1=="Yes", Value1:=NA]
din[Problem2=="Yes", Value2:=NA]
din[Problem3=="Yes", Value3:=NA]

#print table with NA replaced if we have a Problem
#print(din)
#   Timestamp Value1 Value2 Value3 Problem1 Problem2 Problem3
#1:     00:00     32     40     45       No       No       No
#2:     00:05     12     55     48       No       No       No
#3:     00:10     NA     42     55      Yes       No       No
#4:     00:15     NA     33     NA      Yes       No      Yes
#5:     00:20     78     47     75       No       No       No

#use the mean function to replace if I have an NA in the table (just working if Timestamp is a unique id, otherwise you need to generate one and use this in the by argument)
din[is.na(Value1), Value1:=mean(c(Value2,Value3), na.rm=T), by=Timestamp]
din[is.na(Value2), Value2:=mean(c(Value1,Value2), na.rm=T), by=Timestamp]
din[is.na(Value3), Value3:=mean(c(Value1,Value2), na.rm=T), by=Timestamp]

#print final table
#print(din)
#   Timestamp Value1 Value2 Value3 Problem1 Problem2 Problem3
#1:     00:00   32.0     40     45       No       No       No
#2:     00:05   12.0     55     48       No       No       No
#3:     00:10   48.5     42     55      Yes       No       No
#4:     00:15   33.0     33     33      Yes       No      Yes
#5:     00:20   78.0     47     75       No       No       No

``
```

Comment: Problem: This approach doesn't work for an unknown number of Value/Problem pairs.

Comment: True. You could adapt the code with and make a loop over "i" for the number of possible problems and replace my hard coded Value1, Value2, ... with eval(parse())```din[is.na(eval(parse(text=paste0("Value",i)))), Value1:=mean(c(Value2, Value3), na.rm=T), by=Timestamp]```

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for the data:

```
df <- data.frame(value1 = runif(10, min = 0, max = 100),
                 value2 = runif(10, min = 0, max = 100),
                 value3 = runif(10, min = 0, max = 100))

df_problem <- data.frame(problem1 = sample(c('yes','no'), 10, replace = T),
                problem2 = sample(c('yes','no'), 10, replace = T),
                problem3 = sample(c('yes','no'), 10, replace = T))
```

See that I separated the values from the problems. Then:

```
df_problem[df_problem == 'yes'] <- 1
df_problem[df_problem == 'no'] <- NA
df_problem <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(df_problem)), nrow = nrow(df)) #rebuild matrix
```

Finally:

```
df <- df * df_problem

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (T %in% is.na(df[i,])){
    df[i,c(which(is.na(df[i,])))] <- mean(unlist(df[i,]), na.rm = T)
  }
}

df
```